# When running a node.js project through bash script, dotenv file is ignored

Tags: node.js, bash, environment-variables, dotenv

I have the following project structure, where both projects are in node.js

```
/projects
----/project-a
----/project-b
```

Project A is ran through a bash script, which should make sure project B is also running. The path to project B is passed as an argument to the bash script. Here's how the part from the bash script which runs project B looks like:

```sh
if [ -n "${PROJECT_B_PATH}" ]
then
    node "${PROJECT_B_PATH}/index.js"
...
```

It starts the project however it does not read the .env file which exists in project B folder.

I have tried passing the .env file location explicitly with `dotenv_config_path="${PROJECT_B_PATH}/.env"` as well but it didn't work. How can I make this work?

Comment: what does your project_b/index.js looks like?

Comment: I think you need a
 `cd ${PROJECT_B_PATH;
node index.js`

Comment: @Thomas yes it worked like that, I changed it back to the original working folder after running project B. It looks like this now

`current_dir=$(pwd); cd $PROJECT_B_PATH; node ./index.js; cd current_dir;`

Is this a good practice though?

Comment: In my opinion it looks good.